# How do I tunnel SSH though tor(windows)

Tags: windows, vpn, ssh

I'm using Windows.
Whats the best way to securely tunnel and use SSH though Tor, could you guide me to a right direction? I cannot risk stuffing this up and I cannot leak my real IP address, I'm using a VPN just in case.

Comment: What do you want to  know? Have you tried to use an SSH client configured to run over Tor yet?

Comment: Whats the best way to securely connect via SSH without leaving a trace, its to a tor hidden service, I've used PUTTY with TOR as a proxy and connected via the hidden service onion address, is this the best way to accomplish so?

Comment: That would be the standard way, yes

Comment: I've solved it, I use putty and configure tor in the proxy settings, thanks everyone for there help :)